# How to calculate missing clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to calculate previous year missing client records. Sample input 2008 has client id (**1,2,3,4,5,6**) but 2009 has only client id( **2 and 3** ) so Total missing client id (**1,4,5,6**) desired output contain this total number **4** in **2009**. same way for 2007 and 2008. Need a query for desired output.

The **Table structure is**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProductClient](
    [Year] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Product] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Client] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [TotalMissingClient] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Table sample data**

```
Year    Product Client  TotalMissingClient
2008        A    1          NULL
2008        A    2          NULL
2008        A    3          NULL
2007        B    3          NULL
2007        B    2          NULL
2008        B    1          NULL
2007        A    2          NULL
2009        A    2          NULL
2009        A    3          NULL
2008        A    4          NULL
2008        A    5          NULL
2008        A    6          NULL
```

**Desired output is**

```
Year    Product Client  TotalMissingClient
2008        A      1            0
2008        A      2            0
2008        A      3            0
2007        B      3            NULL
2007        B      2            NULL
2008        B      1            NULL
2007        A      2            NULL
2009        A      2            4
2009        A      3            4
2008        A      4            0
2008        A      5            0
2008        A      6            0
```

Comment: Why 2008      B   1    NULL?  What if there is client not in the prior year?

Comment: @paparazzo, 2008 Product B client id (1) this product(B) previous year in 2007 has no entry, so its TotalMissingClient value is null or default value zero.

Comment: In you data there is B in 2007. This is not clear.  Also would have a lot easier if you had sorted by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output contains only those Year/Product combinations that are contained in the base table, meaning that if all clients from the previous year are missing, you won't see that. Example: product B had 1 customer in 2008 but no customer in 2009.
Also, product B had 2 clients in 2007 and 1 (other, so new) client in 2008. Your desired result shows NULL in that case, but shouldn't it show 2 missing clients instead (and 1 new customer)?
The numbers seem to depend only on Year and Product. I think that it would be more usefull to see the whole delta between the previous and the current year, that is the number of customers, missing customers and new customers. This will of course only work if there are no years missing. To hide the delta between the last recorded year and the next year, I used a RANK function:

```
WITH
  compare ([Year], Product, ThisYearClient, PrevYearClient, LoyalClient) AS (
    SELECT ISNULL(this.[Year],  prev.[Year]+1)
      , ISNULL(this.Product, prev.Product)
      , this.Client, prev.Client
      , CASE WHEN this.Client = prev.Client THEN this.Client ELSE NULL END
    FROM tblProductClient this
      FULL JOIN tblProductClient prev
        ON this.Product = prev.Product 
        AND this.Client = prev.Client 
        AND this.[Year] = prev.[Year]+1
  ),
  totals ([Year], Product, ClientsThisYear, ClientsPrevYear, LoyalClients, R) AS (
    SELECT [Year], Product
      , COUNT(ThisYearClient)
      , COUNT(PrevYearClient)
      , COUNT(LoyalClient)
      , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Year] DESC)
    FROM compare
    GROUP BY [Year], Product
  )
SELECT [Year], Product, ClientsThisYear, ClientsPrevYear, LoyalClients 
  , ClientsThisYear - LoyalClients AS NewClients
  , ClientsPrevYear - LoyalClients AS MissingClients
FROM totals WHERE R > 1
ORDER BY [Year], Product
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want is captured by:

```
select t.*,
       (count(distinct client) over () -
        count(distinct clinet) over (partition by year)
       ) as TotalMissingClient
from t;
```

Alas, SQL Server does not support `count(distinct)` with window functions.  So, one method is to use nested window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (max(rank_c) over () -
        max(rank_yc) over (partition by year)
       ) as TotalMissingClient
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by client) as rank_c,
             dense_rank() over (partition by year order by client) as rank_yc
      from t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

I think I misinterpreted the question.  The above solves the problem for *all* clients in all years.  You just want one year comparing to the previous:

```
select t.*, tprev.TotalMissingClient
from t left join
     (select tprev.year, count(distinct tt.client) as TotalMissingClient
      from t tprev left join
           t tt
           on tprev.year = tt.year - 1
              tprev.client = tt.client
      where tt.client is null
      group by tprev.year
     ) tprev
     on tprev.year = t.year - 1;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as 2007 has no previous year like (2006) so 2007 has TotalMissingClient's are zero or null